# AccessDenied using curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm getting a access denied error I updated the access token every time i login to my account of cricket api. I know it maybe duplicate question but I did not find my answer/solution i searches a lot. please help me!

```
<?php
$api_url="https://rest.cricketapi.com/rest/v2/recent_matches/?access_token=using_my_a_token&access_key=using_my_a_key&secret_key=using_s_k";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$api_url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

i want to get data of recent matches from that api.

Comment: Can you share the `access_token`, `access_key` and `secret_key` so we can look and provide you some solution? I guess you can regenerate them once you will get the solution.

Comment: Using that exact data and inserting it into the given URL also gives AccessDenied when called directly in the browser … You either got the URL format wrong somehow, or – your credentials aren’t actually correct.

Comment: @misorude i copied the url of api from their website and then paste the given keys.
is it gives error?
if yes what i can do?

Comment: Why are you passing access_key and secret_key? According to the documentation, this endpoint seems to require only an access token, and optionally a card type. (Yes, removing those does not fix the problem - but brings us right back to the point wwere your access token _not_ being a valid one is really the only logical explanation.)

Comment: (access_key and secret_key are however parameters used in _getting_ an access token in the first place. This looks like you might have tried to make those two separate steps into one …?)

Comment: i removed access_key and secret_key but still getting access denied error.
i need data of recent matches. and not trying to get access token.
(I maybe a slow learner but really need your help)

Comment: Your access token doesn't have the access on that API. Make sure that you have created the App correctly.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your reply. I contacted them and they give me trial for some days. not i used the new token and error is gone